# Obtain a reference to a specific instance of a repeated directive

Tags: angular

I have a list of items like this:

```
<ul>
    <li *ngFor="let item of items" [id]="item.id" matRipple>{{item.text}}</li>
</ul>
```

(matRipple comes from Angular Material)

I wish to create a function that will activate the ripple effect on a specified item. I know that I can use `@ViewChildren(MatRipple)` to get a `QueryList<MatRipple>`, and I can call `ripple.launch()` to activate the effect on any of those elements. But I don't know how to identify a specific element, since `MatRipple` does not read or expose the `id` attribute.

Similarly, I can use `@ViewChildren(MatRipple, { read: ElementRef })` to get a `QueryList<ElementRef>`, and I can use `find(e => e.id == searchTerm)` to retrieve the specific element I want. But from here, I don't know how to get access to the `MatRipple` object.

I'm thinking using `toArray().findIndex(e => e.id == searchTerm)` on `QueryList<ElementRef>` and then `get(index)` on `QueryList<MatRipple>`, but this feels pretty unclean.

I can see that the instances of `MatRipple` have `_elementRef` properties, but these aren't exposed in TypeScript and seem like internal properties that I shouldn't rely on.

I know I could also create my own directive that gets a references to `MatRipple` via DI and sends it to a service, then I could call a function on the service to trigger the ripple for a specific item, but this seems overcomplicated.

Are there any easier approaches that I'm missing?

Comment: The `findIndex()` + `QueryList<MatRipple>` is the one that makes more sense to me. But  I'd run the `findIndex()` against `this.items` instead.

Comment: Cheers, that's what I ended up doing. It works nicely!